# uploading files to amazon aws3 error Forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Yesterday it worked well. Now I have this error.
I run my website locally.

```
Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) excon.error.response :body => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"
 encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access
 Denied</Message><RequestId>C19FF4E3F2</RequestId><HostId>fUbWBNTH+qXOK0+QsFJzdARhvQ+KgRuwTZyklnq3v9WI/gt3I=</HostId></Error>"
 :headers => { "Connection" => "close" "Content-Type" =>
 "application/xml" "Date" => "Sat, 27 Feb 2016 08:06:19 GMT" "Server"
     => "AmazonS3" "x-amz-id-2" => "fUbWBNTH+nYXztwhtbwwWmsRzdARhvQ+KgRuwTZyklnt3I="
 "x-amz-request-id" => "C19FF4E4E9A863F2" } :local_address =>
 "192.168.1.5" :local_port => 60867 :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
 :remote_ip => "54.231.235.77" :status => 403 :status_line => "HTTP/1.1
 403 Forbidden\r\n"
```

upd:I used carrierwave and fog for this and this is my carrierwave config:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
        :provider               => 'AWS',
        :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'], 
        :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region                 => 'us-west-1', # Change this for different AWS region. Default is 'us-east-2'
      :path_style             => true

  }
  config.fog_directory  = "bucket-main1"
  config.fog_public    = true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'} 

end
```

And also it works when I push my code to server but doesn't work locally

Comment: can you provide us with some more details like what did you try to upload,how is your setup and so on?. The question is little vague

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 sure see upd